# Geth on AWS EC2, rpc call networking

Tags: go-ethereum, aws

I'm trying to boot up a Geth node on an AWS EC2 instance and for some reason I'm unable to connect to it via a simple RPC call from outside the instance.  I've done this successfully with a Parity node running in the same exact manor and i'm using the same networking configuration and cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong.  This feels like a networking problem.

**When I try to curl into my geth node I get this message**:

```
curl \
>   --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"1","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[]}' \
>   --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
>   'http://MyEC2IP.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8545'
curl: (7) Failed to connect to MyEC2IP.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 8545: Connection refused
```

**Here is the networking config that works for Parity:**

[image]

**Here is my dumpconfig from geth that seems to line up with my networking config**:

```
~$ geth --cache=4096 --rpc --rpcapi="eth,net,web3" dumpconfig
INFO [01-23|17:28:05.895] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [01-23|17:28:05.896] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.898] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.901] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.901] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.901] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.901] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[01-23|17:28:05.901] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
[Eth]
NetworkId = 1
SyncMode = "fast"
NoPruning = false
NoPrefetch = false
LightPeers = 100
UltraLightFraction = 75
DatabaseCache = 2048
DatabaseFreezer = ""
TrieCleanCache = 1024
TrieDirtyCache = 1024
TrieTimeout = 3600000000000
EnablePreimageRecording = false
EWASMInterpreter = ""
EVMInterpreter = ""

[Eth.Miner]
GasFloor = 8000000
GasCeil = 8000000
GasPrice = 1000000000
Recommit = 3000000000
Noverify = false

[Eth.Ethash]
CacheDir = "ethash"
CachesInMem = 2
CachesOnDisk = 3
DatasetDir = "/home/ubuntu/.ethash"
DatasetsInMem = 1
DatasetsOnDisk = 2
PowMode = 0

[Eth.TxPool]
Locals = []
NoLocals = false
Journal = "transactions.rlp"
Rejournal = 3600000000000
PriceLimit = 1
PriceBump = 10
AccountSlots = 16
GlobalSlots = 4096
AccountQueue = 64
GlobalQueue = 1024
Lifetime = 10800000000000

[Eth.GPO]
Blocks = 20
Percentile = 60

[Shh]
MaxMessageSize = 1048576
MinimumAcceptedPOW = 2e-01
RestrictConnectionBetweenLightClients = true

[Node]
DataDir = "/home/ubuntu/.ethereum"
omitempty = ""
IPCPath = "geth.ipc"
HTTPHost = "127.0.0.1"
HTTPPort = 8545
HTTPVirtualHosts = ["localhost"]
HTTPModules = ["eth", "net", "web3"]
WSPort = 8546
WSModules = ["net", "web3", "eth", "shh"]
GraphQLPort = 8547
GraphQLVirtualHosts = ["localhost"]

[Node.P2P]
MaxPeers = 50
NoDiscovery = false
BootstrapNodes = ["enode://d860a01f9722d78051619d1e2351aba3f43f943f6f00718d1b9baa4101932a1f5011f16bb2b1bb35db20d6fe28fa0bf09636d26a87d31de9ec6203eeedb1f666@18.138.108.67:30303", "enode://22a8232c3abc76a16ae9d6c3b164f98775fe226f0917b0ca871128a74a8e9630b458460865bab457221f1d448dd9791d24c4e5d88786180ac185df813a68d4de@3.209.45.79:30303", "enode://ca6de62fce278f96aea6ec5a2daadb877e51651247cb96ee310a318def462913b653963c155a0ef6c7d50048bba6e6cea881130857413d9f50a621546b590758@34.255.23.113:30303", "enode://279944d8dcd428dffaa7436f25ca0ca43ae19e7bcf94a8fb7d1641651f92d121e972ac2e8f381414b80cc8e5555811c2ec6e1a99bb009b3f53c4c69923e11bd8@35.158.244.151:30303", "enode://8499da03c47d637b20eee24eec3c356c9a2e6148d6fe25ca195c7949ab8ec2c03e3556126b0d7ed644675e78c4318b08691b7b57de10e5f0d40d05b09238fa0a@52.187.207.27:30303", "enode://103858bdb88756c71f15e9b5e09b56dc1be52f0a5021d46301dbbfb7e130029cc9d0d6f73f693bc29b665770fff7da4d34f3c6379fe12721b5d7a0bcb5ca1fc1@191.234.162.198:30303", "enode://715171f50508aba88aecd1250af392a45a330af91d7b90701c436b618c86aaa1589c9184561907bebbb56439b8f8787bc01f49a7c77276c58c1b09822d75e8e8@52.231.165.108:30303", "enode://5d6d7cd20d6da4bb83a1d28cadb5d409b64edf314c0335df658c1a54e32c7c4a7ab7823d57c39b6a757556e68ff1df17c748b698544a55cb488b52479a92b60f@104.42.217.25:30303", "enode://979b7fa28feeb35a4741660a16076f1943202cb72b6af70d327f053e248bab9ba81760f39d0701ef1d8f89cc1fbd2cacba0710a12cd5314d5e0c9021aa3637f9@5.1.83.226:30303"]
BootstrapNodesV5 = ["enode://06051a5573c81934c9554ef2898eb13b33a34b94cf36b202b69fde139ca17a85051979867720d4bdae4323d4943ddf9aeeb6643633aa656e0be843659795007a@35.177.226.168:30303", "enode://0cc5f5ffb5d9098c8b8c62325f3797f56509bff942704687b6530992ac706e2cb946b90a34f1f19548cd3c7baccbcaea354531e5983c7d1bc0dee16ce4b6440b@40.118.3.223:30304", "enode://1c7a64d76c0334b0418c004af2f67c50e36a3be60b5e4790bdac0439d21603469a85fad36f2473c9a80eb043ae60936df905fa28f1ff614c3e5dc34f15dcd2dc@40.118.3.223:30306", "enode://85c85d7143ae8bb96924f2b54f1b3e70d8c4d367af305325d30a61385a432f247d2c75c45c6b4a60335060d072d7f5b35dd1d4c45f76941f62a4f83b6e75daaf@40.118.3.223:30307"]
StaticNodes = []
TrustedNodes = []
ListenAddr = ":30303"
EnableMsgEvents = false

[Node.HTTPTimeouts]
ReadTimeout = 30000000000
WriteTimeout = 30000000000
IdleTimeout = 120000000000
```

The node is running

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to connect" ? Is there an error showing ? Is there nothing ?

Comment: Check the curl text at the top of the post:

curl: (7) Failed to connect to MyEC2IP.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 8545: Connection refused

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Did not see. Are you sure firewall/iptable is not blocking ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain Is that different or the same as what I have screenshotted above?  That same config works for parity.  I figured it would work the same for Geth right?  Do you notice anything wrong with the ports?

Comment: From the log geth is listening at 127.0.0.1 so you will not able to conect from outside. I'm not sure but I think you can pass your external ip at `--rpcaddr` or use 0.0.0.0.

Comment: I am not sure but sometimes by restricting our `8545` port by our IP address in inbound rules we not able to connect the geth or ec2 but you can do by setting `0.0.0.0/0` in inbound rules for port `8545`

Comment: So I tried this and still got a Connection refused.  Is that what you meant?

https://imgur.com/2iQofkb

Comment: I did some additional tests.  I'm able to curl a command to get latest block successfully locally on the ec2 instance.  The geth node is running and accepting rpc calls just fine.  The next test, I stopped the geth node, installed parity, synced parity and that works perfectly.  I'm successfully able to make a remote rpc call into the parity node to get latest block number.  This same thing isn't working on geth for my specific geth config.  So there must be something different about geth in an EC2 instance.  Am I missing anything obvious in my geth config? Or does geth do something unique?

Comment: Looks like I needed to add the following argument: --rpcvhosts=*  After doing that.  It works!

Answer (score 1):

For geth on AWS EC2 you need the `--rpcvhosts=*` argument for the call to get through from an external location.  My network config turned out to be fine.

Comment: This is probably outdated by now. I only needed to open the ports 30303 and 8545, and use the geth flags `--http --http.addr 0.0.0.0` so that it listens for rpc requests over the internet and not only those from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

And for more recent versions (running 1.10.22 here) you should use `--http.vhosts=*`.